# Facebook Application using FQL

Tags: facebook, json, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to develop a Facebook application which shows me all the content of an user id's events.

I found that I can use [FQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Query_Language) for that and I used

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT uid,eid,rsvp_status FROM event_member WHERE uid =me()
```

However, I am clueless how to use this query further. I got the JSON results and would probably be using JSON Object and JSON parser and would love to do it in JavaScript on the frontend, but how do I login for a user and then display the results on the frontend?

I would not prefer PHP but HTML/JavaScript for the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the JavaScript SDK. There are some methods there which make dealing with FQL easier. I am not sure why, but the documentation for these features is hard to find on their site.

Once you have a valid Facebook session established (which I assume you know how to do - if you don't see: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/), you can make async FQL queries like this:

```
var q = FB.Data.query("SELECT uid,eid,rsvp_status FROM event_member WHERE uid =me()");
q.wait(function(result) {  console.log(result); });
```